# mysql enum is not case sensitive it match the first one without case-sensivity

Tags: mysql, enums, case-sensitive, uppercase, lowercase

I have `enum` field that contains `lowercase` and `uppercase` of a same letter,
when I try to update a row and change the value it doesn’t work.

this is the way how reproduce the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `strategy` enum('g','G','r','R') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'g'
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES(1,'test','g');
```

now when I try to change `strategy` from `g` to `G` it doesn't work:

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET `strategy`='G' WHERE id=1;
```

it returnes:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I use `MySQL 5.5`, please help me

**EDIT:**

as mentiond @farshad in his comment,
It use the first match, if I change the order of `enum` and use `'G','g',...` it will always use `G` and you can not change it back to `g`

Comment: It depends on enum order . Mysql returns first matched g character , In my test when you changed order to ('G','g') all rows with 'g' in all cases returns 'G'.  I think right question is why mysql returns first enum character always in case sensitive enum values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution is changing the collation to ASCII:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` CHANGE `strategy` ENUM('g', 'G', 'r', 'R')
CHARACTER SET ASCII COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'g';
```

Answer (score 5):

From the [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html):

> When retrieved, values stored into an ENUM column are displayed using the lettercase that was used in the column definition. Note that ENUM columns can be assigned a character set and collation. For binary or case-sensitive collations, lettercase is taken into account when assigning values to the column.

So you have to change the [column collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-column.html).